# None of the students who have cats have dogs how to apply quantifiers and logical connectives???

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let the universe of discourse consists of all students in your class and let $C(x)$ be “$x$ has a cat”, let $D(x)$ be “$x$ has a dog”, and let $F(x)$   be “$x$ has a ferret.” Express each of the following statements in terms of $C(x), D(x), F(x)$, quantifiers, and logical connectives.

i. A student in your class has a cat, a dog and a ferret.

ii. Some student has a cat and a dog but not a ferret.

iii. No student in your class has a cat, a dog, and a ferret.

iv. For each of the three animals, cats, dogs, and ferrets, there is a student in your class who has one of these animals as a pet.

v. None of the students who have cats have dogs.

I did not understand how to solve number $5$.

Comment: It'd be better if you at least try to write something instead of just saying you don't know how to do it.

Comment: ^ or at least specifically say where you are having a problem.

Comment: I have the problem with no 5 " None of the students who have cats have dogs"

Comment: @SmitPatel Well, in particular, you should say why you have trouble with that one, especially if you solved the others.

Comment: So would it be ¬Ǝx ∈ S (C(x) ^ D(x)? Its little confusing for me to understand. Others are pretty straight so I got them. Thanks

Comment: @SmitPatel That is technically true: it is equivalent to $\forall x\in S(\neg C(x)\lor \neg D(x)$. But remember that $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $B\lor \neg A$, so there's another way that you can write it, which I'd argue is nicer.

Comment: @KevinLong Got it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of all students in the class.

v. can be written as  $\forall x \in S, \neg C(x) \vee \neg D(x)$

Remember:

- $\exists$ means "there exists"
- $\in$ means "is an element of"
- $\forall$ means "for all"
- $\wedge$ means "and"
- $\vee$ means "or"
- $\neg$ means "not"

Comment: There is also a sign for "not" written like this $\lnot$

Comment: thanks! I'll add it right now

Comment: @Sethopolus thanks. I have figured out the rest of them. No 5 was only my concern.

Comment: @SmitPatel My apologies, when I edited your post, I assumed that you wanted all of the statements together, not just singling out number $5$. It does make adding the other four statements redundant, though.

Comment: ok--it would have been better to mention that in the orignal post (you could have even left i - iv off). Have you figured it out now or you still haven't?

Comment: v could be written $\forall x \in S, (C(x) \wedge \neg D(x)) \vee \neg C(x)$, but there may be a way to simplify that.

Comment: @setholopolus That was partially my fault- when I edited, the post listed the first four, then said "I have trouble with this one", then showed the fifth. My logic was that if he listed the first four, he must have also had trouble with those, but it was still my mistake to restructure it.

Comment: ok. I edited my answer so now it answers the edited question. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Oh Okay now I visualized the answer. Thank you.